Random walk metropolis within Gibbs
I tried to implement the Random Walk Metropolis within Gibbs algorithm from Marie Therese Wolfram's article on Inverse Optimal Transport, but I feel like there's an error. In the algorithm, they update each vector and matrix u, v, W one by one, but notably when they update v, they always fix the same value for u, and likewise when they update C. So, I tried to modify the code to achieve convergence of the running averages of the Markov chains as shown in the article, but it doesn't work. I also tried in parallel a simple Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to replace the code, but I still get chains that don't converge.
Algorithm proposed in the article
Link of the article : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.03950
